# dbt Power User 'NoneType' has no attribute 'find_generate_macro_by_name'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, dbt

Using dbt on visual studio code with the dbt Power User extension, and whenever I try to Execute dbt SQL, or I try to show a Compiled dbt Preview, I get the following error:

```
{
  "code": -1,
  "message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_generate_macro_by_name'",
  "data": "\"Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user-0.13.0\\\\dist\\\\dbt_integration.py\\\", line 439, in compile_sql\\n    node = self.compile_node(self.get_server_node(raw_sql, temp_node_id))\\n                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user-0.13.0\\\\dist\\\\dbt_integration.py\\\", line 373, in get_server_node\\n    sql_node = self.sql_parser.parse_remote(sql, node_name)\\n               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user-0.13.0\\\\dist\\\\dbt_integration.py\\\", line 281, in sql_parser\\n    self._sql_parser = SqlBlockParser(self.config, self.dbt, self.config)\\n                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\source\\\\repos\\\\dataplatform-dbt_transform\\\\dbt-env\\\\Lib\\\\site-packages\\\\dbt\\\\parser\\\\base.py\\\", line 105, in __init__\\n    self._update_node_database = RelationUpdate(\\n                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\source\\\\repos\\\\dataplatform-dbt_transform\\\\dbt-env\\\\Lib\\\\site-packages\\\\dbt\\\\parser\\\\base.py\\\", line 74, in __init__\\n    macro = manifest.find_generate_macro_by_name(\\n            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_generate_macro_by_name'\\n\\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\\n\\nTraceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user-0.13.0\\\\dist\\\\node_python_bridge.py\\\", line 104, in <module>\\n    value = eval(_compile(data['code'], '<input>', 'eval'), _locals)\\n            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\\"<input>\\\", line 1, in <module>\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user-0.13.0\\\\dist\\\\dbt_integration.py\\\", line 408, in execute_sql\\n    compilation_result = self.compile_sql(raw_sql)\\n                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\n  File \\\"c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user-0.13.0\\\\dist\\\\dbt_integration.py\\\", line 443, in compile_sql\\n    raise Exception(str(e))\\nException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_generate_macro_by_name'\\n\\n    at ChildProcess.onMessage (c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user-0.13.0\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:5563:184)\\n    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)\\n    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)\\n    at emit (node:internal/child_process:958:14)\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)\""
}
```

Can someone help me on how to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide the code that caused the error in the article or provide a minimum example for reproducing the problem?

Comment: The error comes whenever I try to execute code, it doesn't really matter what code I run. It coud be select * from {{source('source', 'table1')}}

Comment: What means `NoneType`? Have you google the error, prroviding sufficient information can help us understand the problem and provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue and in my case I had the dbt python extension set the to the Pre-Release Version and setting it to the Release Version cleared up the issue for me.

[image: dbt python extension]

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of the error, it seems there are some issues in your underlying Python/DBT environment. The extension is not able to parse the manifest. In version 0.17.4 we have added a functionality to surface these kinds of errors. Please update to the latest version to get more insight into the underlying issue.

Comment: you're the extension maintainer?

Comment: Yes. I am one of the maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue when adding some auto-formatters. In particular, when I added a SQL formatter, it broke some of my macros:

`{% macro macro_name(col) %}` became `{% macro macro_name(col) % }` (note the additional space before `}`)

This made my dbt project fail compilation and, thus, caused the manifest to not work properly. I got alerted by this by the Problems tab in VS Code, but I guess you could try to compile your project `dbt compile` to check if there are any issues with your files.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here that worked for me. https://github.com/AltimateAI/vscode-dbt-power-user/issues/208#issuecomment-1326391314

Simply run `dbt clean` and then `dbt deps`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue after changing my source data from one file to another. I had a generic source file and then started creating one source file for each source.

What worked for me is:

1 - `dbt clean`

2 - `dbt deps`

3 - Reload VS Code window

The first 2 allowed me to `dbt run -s table` without issue. And the 3rd allowed be to run the query on VS Code.